# Find next Outlook event using applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript, osx-mavericks

I want to find out whether there is an outlook event due to start in the next five minutes.

I have the script below:

```
set now to current date
set end_time to now + (5 * minutes)

tell application "Microsoft Outlook" 
    set number_of_events to count (every calendar event whose start time is greater than or equal to now and start time is less than end_time)
end tell
```

Which works for most events, but seems to ignore recurring events. Any ideas how to include these?

Comment: I made a test appointment made it recurring every tuesday and I get the event back when I ran the script, so is a certain type of event maybe a meeting ?

Comment: It seems to work for appointments but not meetings

Comment: what version of outlook are you running . I am not having any problems with meetings either.

Comment: I'm on version 14.4.3

Comment: are they maybe under different accounts or something  ?

Comment: ok. further digging. The events that are not being counted are recurring events sent by somebody else. I can find the master events, but not the recurrence events. It looks like I need to get some some of "next occurrance" function and then pass it each of the master events.

Answer (score 0):

Recurring events are poorly handled via Applescript. AFAIK there is no way to grab information about the current instance of a recurring event. The only way is to break the recurrence and convert it into a standalone event.
[This tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132997/re-outlook-16-50-how-can-i-get-the-event-date-of-a-single-occurrence-of-a-cal/69255990#69255990) is relevant and may have a partial solution.