# Re. Outlook 16.50 , how can I get the event date of a single occurrence of a calendar events series using Applescript?

Tags: outlook, calendar, applescript

The code extracts a pre-selected event properties (attendees, subject, start time etc). All works fine, but I noticed that with recurring meetings a selected event always has the start property of the first meeting instance of the series (hope this makes sense!).

As per the dictionary: recurrence id (date, r/o) : The recurrence id of an event (the date at which the recurring event occurs).

When I use it as per the enclosed it doesn't work - reason is "recurrence id" always returns "missing value". No other property seems appropriate..

Any ideas? - it's driving me nuts!

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
activate

```
if view of the first main window is equal to calendar view then
    set calendarEvent to selection -- grabbing the selected event
    
    
    -- if there are no events selected, warn the user and then quit
    if calendarEvent is missing value then
        display dialog "Please select a calendar event first and then run this script! " with icon 1
        return
    end if
    
    set eventTitle to subject of calendarEvent -- grabbing the event title
    
    set the_properties to properties of calendarEvent
    
    if is recurring of the_properties then
        set eventStart to (recurrence id of the_properties)
    else
        set eventStart to start time of calendarEvent
    end if
    
    set startDate to date string of eventStart
    set startTime to time string of eventStart
    
    
    set docDay to second word of startDate
    set docMonth to third word of startDate
    set docYear to fourth word of startDate
    set docHour to first word of startTime
    set docMin to second word of startTime
    
    set monthList to {January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December}
    
    repeat with mth from 1 to 12
        if docMonth = ((item mth of monthList) as string) then
            set tempMonth to (characters -2 thru -1 of ("0" & mth))
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    set shortMonth to tempMonth
    set shortYear to characters -2 thru -1 in docYear
    
    set noteDateTime to docDay & "/" & shortMonth & "/" & shortYear & " " & docHour & ":" & docMin
    
    set theOrganizer to the organizer of calendarEvent
    
    set noteTitle to eventTitle & ", " & startDate
    
    set emailList to get every email address of every attendee of calendarEvent
    set nameList to ""
    
    set ind to 0
    repeat with theName in emailList
        set ind to (ind + 1)
        if (ind) = 1 then
            if (name of theName) contains "," then -- "Surname, Firstname"
                set (name of theName) to ((name of theName)'s second word & " " & (name of theName)'s first word)
            end if
            set nameList to nameList & " " & (name of theName)
        else
            if (name of theName) contains "," then -- "Surname, Firstname"
                set (name of theName) to ((name of theName)'s second word & " " & (name of theName)'s first word)
            end if
            set nameList to nameList & ("\\par ") & " " & (name of theName)
        end if
    end repeat
else
    display dialog "This is not calendar view! " with icon 1
    return
end if
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if outlook has changed since the 2011 version but the missing value issue apparently endures. However, when I get properties of a recurrence, it includes `icalendar data`, which is a text blob of some 45 entries, one of which is `recurrence-id`. Here is one way to collect that entry:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set rid to "RECURRENCE-ID"
    set aa to calendar event id 1 -- original source
    set ab to calendar event id 2 -- recurrence of aa
    set icda to icalendar data of ab
    set pi to paragraphs of icda
    repeat with x in pi -- each property
        if x contains rid then
            set fulProp to contents of x
        end if
    end repeat

    fulProp
    --> "RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=\"Eastern Time (US & Canada)\":20210628T003000"
    set valu to last word of fulProp
    --> "20210628T003000"
end tell
```

The result looks like it could be parsed for its calendar event values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, RECURRENCE-ID still shows the master event date or have I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: Hmm… it looks like outlook needs something to refresh before the properties change. For example, edit the recurrence in a small way (e.g. change the end time by 1 minute). Then select and run the script. It should provide that particular instance's data — including the native property 'recurrence id'. Weird and annoying. At least that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: Glad it's not me going mad! If I amend the occurrence won't it send a meeting update? I'm guessing that this works as it breaks the event from the series... Is there a way of finding the current selected day and working it out from there?

Comment: set xy to selection; start time of xy (replace the ; with a return)

Comment: Here is something to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29949611/7410243

Comment: Thanks Mockman, but unfortunately set xy to selection; start time of xy doesn't work :( It still reflects the start time of the series of meetings.

Comment: Well, that is the way :) Did you get a chance to look at the other question? The answer there suggests a bug, with a workaround, which seems to do the equivalent of amending without actually doing so — so it wouldn't trigger a resend. Quirky issue and not much to be found on it, even on Microsoft sites.

Answer (score 0):

I tried basically every attribute of a calendar event, and to my knowledge there is no way to get properties related to individual occurrences of a recurring event, other than the event id using the script Mockman linked to. Even the iCal exports are identical. Also, I couldn't find a way to grab the day of the currently selected event... however, when I tried that script, I realized that just the act of getting the occurrence of a recurring calendar event *makes it no longer recurring*, and after that the script works normally 
so one possible logic is as follows:

1. is the event recurring?
2. if yes, is there an event today? (assuming that in most cases you are trying to access the event on the same day

3a) if yes, get occurrence at today's date and hour (this will break the recurrence of this event), then grab start time etc.

3b) if not, get start date of recurring event, event rate, day of the week etc, parse this information and get occurrence for all the events for one year or so (they will all become individual events), then grab dates.

If anyone knows how to grab the day of a selected calendar event (for example a recurrent one) then 3b is not needed...

Comment: `set ab to selection; set cd to start time of ab; short date string of cd;`. You can substitute `end time` or `recurrence id` for `start time`. Bugginess applies. 'cd' is a standard date object so you can use any of the date functions with it.

Comment: this doesn't work for recurring events, which is the problem we are trying to address here...

Comment: It works for them once they've been 'refreshed', as stated in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution: this snippet will deal with recurring events by 'disconnecting' the event from the series, but only if *run the same day*. This is my use case 99% of the time (I run the script with Alfred right before a meeting), but it might not work for others. Add this snippet at line 24 of the previous script, or use the [revised script](https://github.com/giovannicoppola/Meeting-Notes/blob/main/v02_Markdown%20Clipboard).

```
set isRec to is recurring of calendarEvent

    if isRec = true then
        set tdate to current date
        set sdate to start time of calendarEvent # because current date will have also current time, extract the time from the event (series)
        tell me to set time of tdate to time of sdate
        set myID to id of calendarEvent
        
        
        try
            set calendarEvent to get occurrence of calendar event id myID at tdate
            set eventStart to start time of calendarEvent
            
        on error
            
            display dialog "❗This is a recurrent event, but I see no occurrences on " & tdate with icon 1
            
        end try
    end if
```